# Managing multiple users in php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I am a newbie to php.

I just learned that you can create a session variable for a user after his login such as

```
$_SESSION['id']=****some value(say 3)******;
```

and this session variable is maintained as long as he doesn't log out(i.e. you clear this session variable using session_destroy).

Now , I have a confusion that if another user logs in then won't this `id` variable be overwritten thus logging the previous user out?
If this is true ,then what can I do to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

PHP sessions are tied to a user by a unique (random) ID string, generated the first time you invoke session_start() for a user. That ID is stored in the client browser as a cookie (or possibly via hidden form fields/query parameters).

Even though $_SESSION is used throughout the code, the CONTENTS of that $_SESSION array are tied to a particular user via that ID string. That means if I hit your site, $_SESSION will contain my details. If you hit your site, $_SESSION will contain your details.

There should be no practical way for my details to "leak" in your session, or vice versa. Destroying my session will not destroy yours, because yours is a completely different session, with a different ID.

Answer (score 0):

All sessions are tied to a [unique session ID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_ID). This is typically set inside the user's cookie.

Comment: :So how the server distinguishes `id` session variable for each user.Does it uses cookies for it by sending it to user automatically,even if we haven't written code to create cookies?